# How to disable auto complete pops up in sublime when i press semicolon and space ;

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext, sublimetext4

I am a new user of sublime. I recently moved from vscode to get the faster using experience in sublime. But one thing in sublime really depressed me. There is no other autocompletion package works in my sublime except for `sublime code intel`.     With other packages, I can not be able to get the autocomplete popup when I type.

So that's why I need to stay with only `sublime code intel`. The problem with the package is I get auto complete popup when I even type `space or semicolon (;)`. Which is really disturbing. There is one solution to get rid of it. Either pressing `shift + enter or escape key`. It is really annoying. Can anyone help me with it, pls.

N.B. I am using sublime text 4 in Linux. Also, I have read some previous questions but can not be able to get the solution.

Comment: There are autocompletion engines for most popular languages available in [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io), many of them based on the [`LSP`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/LSP) system. What language(s) are you using?

Comment: Currenly i am working with javascript, react and .jsx syntax..  I have tried previously with ```all autocomplete```. But it recently stopped working after when i tried ```sublime code intel``` for getting more autosuggestions.. So can you pls help me.. @MattDMo

Comment: I have the same issue with no extra package installed, seems the only way to disable it is to disable auto_complete...

Answer (score 2):

I've found the way to disable semicolons popup by edit **setting.auto_complete_selector**.

*"meta.tag, source - punctuation.terminator - comment - string.quoted.double.block - string.quoted.single.block - string.unquoted.heredoc"*

The trick is adding *- punctuation.terminator* after *source* selector.
This will remove semicolons from the auto_complete_selector according to
[the doc of Selector](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/selectors.html) and [the doc of scope_naming](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/scope_naming.html#punctuation).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, there are plenty auto-completes including the default auto complete which comes with sublime.

You can actually remove code-intel and just use all auto-complete along side with the default auto-complete and LSP
and if you have any question feel free to ask on the official discord https://discord.gg/D43Pecu

**BESIDES SUBLIME CODE INTEL MAKES YOUR SUBLIME VERY LAGGY**

Comment: yeah right sublime code intel is so slow and laggy.. which doesn't let me type firster..

Answer (score 0):

ST4 introduced context aware autocompletion so you don't need anything else. It's good enough and fast.But if you are a fan of autocomplete that vscode provides then you can use  -----

1. **LSP** - https://packagecontrol.io/packages/LSP
2. **LSP-typescript** - https://packagecontrol.io/packges/LSP-typescript
3. **LSP-HTML** - https://packagecontrol.io/packages/LSP-html
4. **LSP-Css** - https://packagecontrol.io/packages/LSP-css
5. **LSP-Json** - https://packagecontrol.io/packages/LSP-json
6. **LSP-eslint** - https://packagecontrol.io/packages/LSP-eslint

If you don't have a powerful machine then I would advice you to not use LSP because it creates a node runtime in the background and that might eat up all your resources. Anyways I feel that ST4 native autosuggestion are good enough. But LSP is much more than an autocomplete engine. So you know, it just depends on your use case.

Personally I prefer using LSP and disabling it's autocomplete suggestions because it takes like 5 seconds for it to suggest something every time I press a key, while ST4 completions are near about instant.

You can also go to Sublime text forum - https://forum.sublimetext.com/ If you have any queries.

Sublime​Code​Intel - https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeCodeIntel was last updated 4 years ago. 4 years is like a decade in web development so I doubt you'll get anything good enough from that package.

All Autocomplete - https://packagecontrol.io/packages/All%20Autocomplete was last updated 2 years ago.

Note - Don't forget to set your language on the right side of your status bar. Otherwise auto completion and syntax highlighting will not work properly. For example, if you are writing jsx then select jsx and not javascript, if you are using tsx then select tsx not typescript. That goes for all the other options.

You can send me an email if you need any other assistance - `connect@surajmishra.dev`

Edit - I just realized this answer does not covers the asked question but I am still going to keep it up in case someone else finds it useful.